# Fetch min value excluding zero in column in SAP BO WEBI?

Tags: sql, aggregate, webi

I have a column in SAP BO WEBI. For example, I have the following values in my column.

| MONTH |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 3 |

When I try the Min() function in WEBI like this Min([MONTH]),
it returns 0 for me. But I want the value 2 to come. So I want to return the non-zero minimum value. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `min(month)` use `min(case when month <> 0 then month end)` ? Or even shorter `min(nullif(month, 0))`.

Answer (score 0):

In WebI this should do it...

```
=Min([Month]) Where ([Month] > 0)
```

Here is what it looks like with data from the eFashion universe.

[image]